# UWP C# Bluetooth Low Energy: Multiple concurrent connections not working

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

In my UWP Windows 10 App, I am using Window.Devices.Bluetooth to scan and connect to in-house Bluetooth Low Energy devices. Below is the code sample used for connecting (The mac addresses are known for in-house devices)
The test application using following two APIs:

```
 using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth;
 using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile;
 var bleDevice = BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync
 var services = bleDevice.GetGattServicesAsync
```

With multiple devices advertising, the API GetGattServicesAsync works fine for the first device but return 'Unreachable' status when connection is attempted while first device is still connected. We see same behavior for either of the devices connected first.

Similar functionality was working fine in the past but isn't working with recent version of windows and SDK (Windows 10 21H1, SDK target 19041, SDK min 17134).

Am I missing some configuration or this functionality isn't supported anymore. The source code of a minimal example is available here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SMU1LE6LJIxxvsj3MdLpHZJfJOUsd3vB

Thanks

Comment: Could you tell more about the system and apps target version that could work well?

Comment: I had this working in my older app from 2019 with target SDK 10.0.17763.0 and minimum 10.0.16299.0. However, targeting the older SDK versions on latest windows (21H1) still has the issue.

Comment: So the problem only occurs in 21h1 OS right ?

Comment: I do not test this configuration often so its already be broken on one of previous version of Windows 10

Comment: Could your try to re-pair the ble and test again?

Comment: Pairing is never done for these devices (in-house). Connection works fine on Windows, Android and iOS without pairing

Comment: Ok, I got it, I will do more researching for this thread, and If I have any updates, I will update below.

Comment: If helps, I have created a wireshark log with Bluetooth Virtual Sniffer. The log is available here
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1T22f69tkHScrmTi9oqW7V-16n_1mkEcL

The connection to first device is initiated at time 6.23 seconds which goes well and PC does the service discovery. And then at time 11.43 second, second connection is initiated and after 7-8 seconds, Host send the cancel connection request. And when I check in the device FW, the connection callback is never received for the 2nd device.

Comment: Ok, Good, if you have solve the problem, you could post answer for this thread, and mark yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be issue with BT's driver on Lenovo P52 laptop. The issue initially resolved by using external CSR4.0 dongle instead of internal BT. And after recent windows update to Intel Wireless Bluetooth driver v22.50.0.4, the multiple connections are also working on internal BT again.